# trying to use sway, but the touchpad doesn't work

Tags: archlinux, wayland, touchpad

I've added the touchpad to te .config/sway/config file but it doesn't  work, I've  also tried  to see libinput debug-events, but when i try to use the touchpad  it doesn't seem to be revelated.
(I have just installed a clean version of archlinux)

`swaymsg -t get_inputs`
returns:
1)Identifier: "2:14:ETPS/2_Elantech_Touchpad"

And also
2)Identifier: "1267:37:Elan_Touchpad"

So I've  added to .config/sway/config

Input "the identifier 1" {
dwt enabled
tap enabled
middle_emulation enabled
natural_scroll enabled

}
Input "the identifier 2" {
dwt enabled
tap enabled
natural_scroll enabled
middle_emulation enabled

}

But the touchpad still don't work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the device identifier, I tested a few minutes ago.

```
input "type:touchpad" { dwt enabled tap enabled }
```